# passing python -c to running program in gdb

Tags: python, c, gdb, exploit

I'm currently playing with this C program (yes I know its vuln).

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[64];
    gets(buffer);
}
```

When I put it into gdb, I want to run it then pass it a python command. eg

```
gdb -q test
Reading symbols from test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/test 
python -c 'print "A" * 100'
[Inferior 1 (process 14912) exited normally]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/test 
`python -c 'print "A" * 100'`
[Inferior 1 (process 14917) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Is it actually possible to pass a python command to the program after running this? Or is it best to just do this out of gdb and pipe it in?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> Is it actually possible to pass a python command to the program after running this?

Yes, but you are doing it wrong. What your command does:

```
/tmp/test `python  -c 'print "A" * 100'`
```

which is equivalent to:

```
/tmp/test AAAAA...A
```

What you want:

```
(gdb) run <(python -c 'print "A" * 100')
```

which is equivalent to:

```
echo "AAAAA...A" | /tmp/test
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this on an exploit box i was using and got: `(gdb) run <(python -c 'print "A" * 100')
Starting program: /opt/protostar/bin/stack4 <(python -c 'print "A" * 100')
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
During startup program exited with code 2.
` I imagine this is just an issue with the exploit box setup.

Although I tried it on my actual system and gdb resorted to just hanging.